# ansible display file content to stdout

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm using `ansible 2.9.3` and I'm having trouble trying to display the content of a file from the target machine, this is my playbook :

```
-
  name: Display content of resolv.conf
  hosts: jenkins
  tasks:
    - name: Display resolv.conf contents
      command: cat resolv.conf chdir=/etc
      register: command_output

    - name: Print to console
      debug: msg = "{{command_output.stdout}}"
```

And my task `Print to console` returns:

```
TASK [Print to console] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [jenkins] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

I wanted to have the content of the file to stdout, what am I missing ? Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting the `msg` on a separate line than `debug` like this and use a `:` instead of an `=` :

```
-
  name: Display content of resolv.conf
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Display resolv.conf contents
      command: cat resolv.conf chdir=/etc
      register: command_output

    - name: Print to console
      debug:
        msg: "{{command_output.stdout}}"
```

This was my output:

> TASK [Display resolv.conf contents] ******************************************************************************************************************************
>   changed: [127.0.0.1]
>
> TASK [Print to console] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
>       "msg": "#\n# macOS Notice\n#\n# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address\n# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most\n# processes on this system.\n#\n# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:\n#   scutil --dns\n#\n# SEE ALSO\n#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)\n#\n# This file is automatically generated.\n#\ndomain attlocal.net\nnameserver 192.168.1.254\nnameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4"
>   }

Comment: A great answer. Maybe it is an idea to add `{{ command_output.stdout_lines }}`  so the new lines are preserved and not printed as `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ansible.builtin.file` lookup plugin to print content of the file, e.g.

```
- ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: lookup('ansible.builtin.file', '/etc/resolv.conf')
```

However by default, lookup plugins are always executes on the controller (localhost) ([GH-78845](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/78845#issuecomment-1254140067)), so you've to copy the file first (e.g. using [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) module first).

See docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces around the equal sign "="

```
debug: msg="{{command_output.stdout}}"
```